# How to keep Golang WebAssembly Instance Running after error and Exit (Code:2)

Tags: javascript, go, webassembly

I have this program to send bytes from JavaScript to Golang WebAssembly using the code:

```golang
func sendBytes(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
    if len(args) < 1 {
        return 0
    }
    array := args[0]
    fmt.Println(array.Type())

    buf := make([]byte, array.Length())
    n := js.CopyBytesToGo(buf, array)
    fmt.Println(buf)
    return n
}

func registerCallbacks() {
    js.Global().Set("sendBytes", js.FuncOf(sendBytes))
}
```

When I execute `sendBytes` with something else than `Uint8Array`,
I am getting my whole instance killed in the browser and I have to run it again. This is [screenshot of how I execute sendBytes().](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjcWa.png)
[image]

How can I keep it running no matter what error happened?

Comment: From your screenshot, the reason leading to the WASM code exit was a panic `call of Value.SetIndex on number` when you pass a number to `sendBytes()`, this function is supposed to call on array, so what do you want? Why do you need to call it on number?

Comment: Just in case it's called on anything else and golang will panic. I would like to continue working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your screenshot, when you passed a number to `sendBytes()`, the line of code `array.Length()` would lead to a panic, then the WASM code would exit. As you know `sendBytes()` should not be called on a number.

If you indeed need it to keep running, you can use [`recover`](https://go.dev/blog/defer-panic-and-recover) in Go, similar to:

```golang
func sendBytes(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("Recovered from", r)
        }
    }() 

    if len(args) < 1 {
        return 0
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's recover() I've been looking for... :)